# Fastest way to export data of huge Python lists to a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, bigdata

I am searching for the most performant way to export the elements of up to ten Python lists `[x1, x2, x3, ... xn], [y1, y2, y3, ... yn], [z1, z2, z3, ... zn], ...` to a text file with a structure as follows:

```
x1 y1 z1  .  .  . 
x2 y2 z2  .  .  .
x3 y3 z3  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .  .  .
xn yn zn  .  .  .
```

What makes it challenging is that each list may have up to 1 million elements (only float or int numbers)

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `csv` module and the `writerows` function to write the list of lists in one line.

Small standalone test:

```
import random,time


lists = [[random.randint(1,500) for _ in range(100000)] for _ in range(100)]

import csv
start_time=time.time()

with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f,delimiter=" ")
    cw.writerows(lists)

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

writes 100 lines of 100000 elements in 2 seconds on my machine (generating the list was slower than writing them back)

So you're just limited by the memory of your input list.

EDIT: this code above does not "transpose" properly so it's cheating. Using `zip` (python 3) does the trick directly using `writerows` so the code doesn't change much:

```
import random,time

n=1000000
list1 = list(range(1,n))
list2 = list(range(n+1,n*2))
list3 = list(range(2*n+1,n*3))

import csv
start_time=time.time()

with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f,delimiter=" ")
    cw.writerows(zip(list1,list2,list3))

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

for python2, use `itertools.izip` because `zip` returns a list: not memory-efficient. Python 2 compliant code:

```
import itertools
with open("out.csv","wb") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f,delimiter=" ")
    cw.writerows(itertools.izip(list1,list2,list3))
```

If you have a list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [list1,list2,list3]
```

you can use `*` to expand the list into arguments for `zip` or `izip`:

```
cw.writerows(zip(*lists_of_lists))

cw.writerows(itertools.izip(*lists_of_lists))
```

Comment: I think OP wants to zip the lists and write respective elements in single row. Check my solution. Do you know an even faster way?

Comment: I misread the zip aspect. Your solution works. Do you need `izip` for python 3? `zip` already returns an iterator.

Comment: Mohammad is right. His solution is already very fast. I would also be interested if there is an even faster way.

Comment: @Rickson Go to Python chatroom and post this question's link there. If there is a more faster way, I guess someone might be knowing there.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah it was not so clear at first. I am on Python2.7. Python3 has izip by default? Didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: Check my updated answer with the transpose snippet. Using `writerows` without a loop instead of `writerow` in a loop should be even faster (also edited to be able to use python 2)

Comment: Would it be possible to pass a list of list in the python2 code instead of n single lists without performance losses?

Comment: Thanks but what about your comment regarding using izip instead of zip because of memory efficiency?

Comment: you can use this trick for all functions. zip and izip included.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
from itertools import izip
import csv

with open('new_file', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    for a in izip(l1, l2, ....., l10):
        writer.writerow(a)
```